# Asked to Login after 15 Minutes

Tags: raspbian, login

I have disabled screen blanking and screen saver. I am running a script which displays images or video. I have also made it autologin & edited autostart file to run my script after bootup on GUI.

After 15 minutes it asks to login. I want to remove this setting, please give me suggestions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you still have a screensaver running after all. If you can find out which one it is, the proper solution is to disable or uninstall it.

A quick and dirty solution could be to artificially produce user input from within your script. Try something like

```
xdotool mousemove 0 0
```

or

```
xdotool key Backspace
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working fine in Ubuntu,  But in raspbian stretch when I am running a script it asking to log in after 15 minutes. How it can be avoided. I want to avoid auto lock (screen asking log in completely).